# Transform a ajax json object into multiple texts boxes values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

So i am having the next input trough and ajax call:

```
var json = {
  "id_u":"1",
  "nombre_usuario":"JESUS",
  "apellido_paterno_usuario":"DIAZ",
}
```

I have several text inputs with the associated name of each JSON object as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="id_u">
<input type="text" name="nombre_usuario">
<input type="text" name="apellido_paterno_usuario">
```

What i want to have a value to each input. Like this:

```
<input type="text" name="id_u" value="1">
<input type="text" name="nombre_usuario" value="jesus">
<input type="text" name="apellido_paterno_usuario" value="diaz">
```

I know that i can do with jQuery with jQuery function:

```
$("[name=]").val();
```

The problem is that i have a lot of fields to complete. Si i would like to do it faster.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you're going to do a lot of this "data-binding" type stuff, you might want to look into MVVM frameworks like Knockout or Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<input type="text" name="id_u">
<input type="text" name="nombre_usuario">
<input type="text" name="apellido_paterno_usuario">

<script>

var json = {
    "id_u":"1",
    "nombre_usuario":"JESUS",
    "apellido_paterno_usuario":"DIAZ"
};

for (var key in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        $("[name=" + key + "]").val(json[key]);
    }
}

</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GCy2a/